# Python selecting k elements form an array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to select all possible sub-arrays of an array of length `n` which have `k` elements. I have just started with Python and not sure how to start with it.

I know there will be `nCk` (`n` choose `k`)  but don't know how to start. Could anyone please give me a hint or a method I could use?

```
$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!$$
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an array of arrays - like this:
[[0], [0, 0], [0]....]

All possible sub-arrays with length x would be:

```
def get_subarrays_of_length(in_array, length):
    out_array = []
    for item in in_array:
        if len(item) == length:
            out_array.append(item)
    return out_array
```

This isn't very performant, if you have a large array, you may find yourself in a pickle, but python passes objects by reference if I recall, so you should be fine - it sounds a bit like homework though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)?

**Example:**

```
In [2]: import itertools
In [3]: a = [1,2,3,4]
In [4]: print( list(itertools.combinations( a, 2 )) )
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```